# Gráfico ggplot eixo x

Tags: r, ggplot2

Esse é meu data.frame:

```
    datamatrix=structure(list(month = c(1980, 1980.08333333333, 1980.16666666667, 
1980.25, 1980.33333333333, 1980.41666666667, 1980.5, 1980.58333333333, 
1980.66666666667, 1980.75, 1980.83333333333, 1980.91666666667, 
1981, 1981.08333333333, 1981.16666666667, 1981.25, 1981.33333333333, 
1981.41666666667, 1981.5, 1981.58333333333, 1981.66666666667, 
1981.75, 1981.83333333333, 1981.91666666667, 1982, 1982.08333333333, 
1982.16666666667, 1982.25, 1982.33333333333, 1982.41666666667, 
1982.5, 1982.58333333333, 1982.66666666667, 1982.75, 1982.83333333333, 
1982.91666666667, 1983, 1983.08333333333, 1983.16666666667, 1983.25, 
1983.33333333333, 1983.41666666667, 1983.5, 1983.58333333333, 
1983.66666666667, 1983.75, 1983.83333333333, 1983.91666666667, 
1984, 1984.08333333333, 1984.16666666667, 1984.25, 1984.33333333333, 
1984.41666666667, 1984.5, 1984.58333333333, 1984.66666666667, 
1984.75, 1984.83333333333, 1984.91666666667, 1985, 1985.08333333333, 
1985.16666666667, 1985.25, 1985.33333333333, 1985.41666666667, 
1985.5, 1985.58333333333, 1985.66666666667, 1985.75, 1985.83333333333, 
1985.91666666667, 1986, 1986.08333333333, 1986.16666666667, 1986.25, 
1986.33333333333, 1986.41666666667, 1986.5, 1986.58333333333, 
1986.66666666667, 1986.75, 1986.83333333333, 1986.91666666667, 
1987, 1987.08333333333, 1987.16666666667, 1987.25, 1987.33333333333, 
1987.41666666667, 1987.5, 1987.58333333333, 1987.66666666667, 
1987.75, 1987.83333333333, 1987.91666666667, 1988, 1988.08333333333, 
1988.16666666667, 1988.25, 1988.33333333333, 1988.41666666667, 
1988.5, 1988.58333333333, 1988.66666666667, 1988.75, 1988.83333333333, 
1988.91666666667, 1989, 1989.08333333333, 1989.16666666667, 1989.25, 
1989.33333333333, 1989.41666666667, 1989.5, 1989.58333333333, 
1989.66666666667, 1989.75, 1989.83333333333, 1989.91666666667, 
1990, 1990.08333333333, 1990.16666666667, 1990.25, 1990.33333333333, 
1990.41666666667, 1990.5, 1990.58333333333, 1990.66666666667, 
1990.75, 1990.83333333333, 1990.91666666667, 1991, 1991.08333333333, 
1991.16666666667, 1991.25, 1991.33333333333, 1991.41666666667, 
1991.5, 1991.58333333333, 1991.66666666667, 1991.75, 1991.83333333333, 
1991.91666666667, 1992, 1992.08333333333, 1992.16666666667, 1992.25, 
1992.33333333333, 1992.41666666667, 1992.5, 1992.58333333333, 
1992.66666666667, 1992.75, 1992.83333333333, 1992.91666666667, 
1993, 1993.08333333333, 1993.16666666667, 1993.25, 1993.33333333333, 
1993.41666666667, 1993.5, 1993.58333333333, 1993.66666666667, 
1993.75, 1993.83333333333, 1993.91666666667, 1994, 1994.08333333333, 
1994.16666666667, 1994.25, 1994.33333333333, 1994.41666666667, 
1994.5, 1994.58333333333, 1994.66666666667, 1994.75, 1994.83333333333, 
1994.91666666667, 1995, 1995.08333333333, 1995.16666666667, 1995.25, 
1995.33333333333, 1995.41666666667, 1995.5, 1995.58333333333, 
1995.66666666667, 1995.75, 1995.83333333333, 1995.91666666667, 
1996, 1996.08333333333, 1996.16666666667, 1996.25, 1996.33333333333, 
1996.41666666667, 1996.5, 1996.58333333333, 1996.66666666667, 
1996.75, 1996.83333333333, 1996.91666666667, 1997, 1997.08333333333, 
1997.16666666667, 1997.25, 1997.33333333333, 1997.41666666667, 
1997.5, 1997.58333333333, 1997.66666666667, 1997.75, 1997.83333333333, 
1997.91666666667, 1998, 1998.08333333333, 1998.16666666667, 1998.25, 
1998.33333333333, 1998.41666666667, 1998.5, 1998.58333333333, 
1998.66666666667, 1998.75, 1998.83333333333, 1998.91666666667, 
1999, 1999.08333333333, 1999.16666666667, 1999.25, 1999.33333333333, 
1999.41666666667, 1999.5, 1999.58333333333, 1999.66666666667, 
1999.75, 1999.83333333333, 1999.91666666667, 2000, 2000.08333333333, 
2000.16666666667, 2000.25, 2000.33333333333, 2000.41666666667, 
2000.5, 2000.58333333333, 2000.66666666667, 2000.75, 2000.83333333333, 
2000.91666666667, 2001, 2001.08333333333, 2001.16666666667, 2001.25, 
2001.33333333333, 2001.41666666667, 2001.5, 2001.58333333333, 
2001.66666666667, 2001.75, 2001.83333333333, 2001.91666666667, 
2002, 2002.08333333333, 2002.16666666667, 2002.25, 2002.33333333333, 
2002.41666666667, 2002.5, 2002.58333333333, 2002.66666666667, 
2002.75, 2002.83333333333, 2002.91666666667, 2003, 2003.08333333333, 
2003.16666666667, 2003.25, 2003.33333333333, 2003.41666666667, 
2003.5, 2003.58333333333, 2003.66666666667, 2003.75, 2003.83333333333, 
2003.91666666667, 2004, 2004.08333333333, 2004.16666666667, 2004.25, 
2004.33333333333, 2004.41666666667, 2004.5, 2004.58333333333, 
2004.66666666667, 2004.75, 2004.83333333333, 2004.91666666667, 
2005, 2005.08333333333, 2005.16666666667, 2005.25, 2005.33333333333, 
2005.41666666667, 2005.5, 2005.58333333333, 2005.66666666667, 
2005.75, 2005.83333333333, 2005.91666666667, 2006, 2006.08333333333, 
2006.16666666667, 2006.25, 2006.33333333333, 2006.41666666667, 
2006.5, 2006.58333333333, 2006.66666666667, 2006.75, 2006.83333333333, 
2006.91666666667, 2007, 2007.08333333333, 2007.16666666667, 2007.25, 
2007.33333333333, 2007.41666666667, 2007.5, 2007.58333333333, 
2007.66666666667, 2007.75, 2007.83333333333, 2007.91666666667, 
2008, 2008.08333333333, 2008.16666666667, 2008.25, 2008.33333333333, 
2008.41666666667, 2008.5, 2008.58333333333, 2008.66666666667, 
2008.75, 2008.83333333333, 2008.91666666667, 2009, 2009.08333333333, 
2009.16666666667, 2009.25, 2009.33333333333, 2009.41666666667, 
2009.5, 2009.58333333333, 2009.66666666667), Variables = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), value = c(-1.41568693359639, 
-1.38516781332907, -1.33408605520775, -1.28856785338743, -1.21662851332014, 
-1.11360334041262, -1.08256807987313, -0.952667418503549, -0.909214414583732, 
-0.807884773862507, -0.769773249349519, -0.735917482383455, -0.726494469171924, 
-0.712607036502983, -0.706441045760995, -0.677574082262706, -0.675338401345027, 
-0.655352504062519, -0.564547238566527, -0.562183781525219, -0.549443117336325, 
-0.548087281498695, -0.543016203003817, -0.533126378931867, -0.532695336350073, 
-0.530469630789224, -0.527525321142688, -0.527470069073422, -0.525078916633687, 
-0.524978135836644, -0.524967717026583, -0.524922608041474, -0.514097317192378, 
-0.514097317192378, -0.508129683911902, -0.504292007906129, -0.498851204142117, 
-0.495584944590002, -0.492071277840454, -0.489056358893004, -0.487272656620384, 
-0.484499997403621, -0.480020154034502, -0.474111512508358, -0.469468593323502, 
-0.468469045395129, -0.465925575842072, -0.465738336692932, -0.464055747310196, 
-0.463014224813565, -0.461812681843618, -0.454489426775255, -0.446372410885833, 
-0.445568964002631, -0.443947184074098, -0.441084154380825, -0.438077287636174, 
-0.432439683755676, -0.432432720184197, -0.430105304507158, -0.427393743805008, 
-0.419178254253137, -0.41647903518232, -0.416451641134128, -0.411505792292203, 
-0.402879769368711, -0.40267797814126, -0.401803478017315, -0.400912976001817, 
-0.395428739483842, -0.394808845835056, -0.392662879606687, -0.391621076844061, 
-0.390288469761387, -0.389306604694823, -0.389046949326427, -0.381361760898008, 
-0.378029736715833, -0.377825052255658, -0.377336780208399, -0.374481350637171, 
-0.373481768737918, -0.373047317687921, -0.372835291128594, -0.36930637799298, 
-0.36916877586257, -0.367662532114864, -0.365442151372518, -0.36511371103752, 
-0.356827254743452, -0.356792132280659, -0.356224734494068, -0.35371903403056, 
-0.35366349319599, -0.353430882180668, -0.353402847858092, -0.350980501008437, 
-0.350943769865209, -0.347942125048003, -0.341907847650033, -0.340268472967654, 
-0.334633081254016, -0.333988711449411, -0.326222158763729, -0.324356380556427, 
-0.319787533492688, -0.317988822619248, -0.317921439695571, -0.317175391159428, 
-0.315810692039914, -0.312957350542058, -0.306579036337544, -0.302953053386637, 
-0.300413595156384, -0.296501683127009, -0.295453636530764, -0.293926629261683, 
-0.293805270733207, -0.291057052694258, -0.288453151106909, -0.286239014649179, 
-0.284382894114638, -0.28106740608963, -0.275087112409856, -0.274686946270055, 
-0.273933113340536, -0.272918156041105, -0.272682424403724, -0.272446235763058, 
-0.269740322870407, -0.268102365924795, -0.265504470918577, -0.264530173307026, 
-0.253721087126259, -0.253721087126259, -0.253083575832663, -0.251713174813214, 
-0.248224763183071, -0.248092935255913, -0.247030147986705, -0.246266055259694, 
-0.243203131768278, -0.242917802213986, -0.242097642021515, -0.239590033032893, 
-0.232344103616537, -0.228361119776281, -0.225461476501073, -0.221111597102107, 
-0.220602619502198, -0.218327013687026, -0.218141983694319, -0.214650762953939, 
-0.211893401223788, -0.20752219428392, -0.202679450329365, -0.20137955134677, 
-0.197754781684186, -0.197060272066931, -0.193283904517936, -0.184412822311837, 
-0.179996837602987, -0.179365066199714, -0.178890712980355, -0.175118174261638, 
-0.170279742604136, -0.16888421593357, -0.16512373566585, -0.159065034283791, 
-0.157073043593653, -0.153672108105402, -0.146136005541048, -0.140804187856417, 
-0.140204473681121, -0.134691188774738, -0.122798305688317, -0.122333451517261, 
-0.120303802949606, -0.118777678753149, -0.114707225086815, -0.11096409241979, 
-0.11096409241979, -0.110649377750615, -0.109191297035247, -0.107866000604286, 
-0.102670832052676, -0.0972107171661226, -0.0912478450381159, 
-0.0863861939466677, -0.0811294637005102, -0.0811201833654124, 
-0.0792852917606622, -0.0756548749112128, -0.0755619087291303, 
-0.0665724067054987, -0.0558680414992422, -0.0556948501129953, 
-0.055044387018447, -0.0533945198213376, -0.0506868101414675, 
-0.0501976268693629, -0.0474329812447739, -0.0473107406986237, 
-0.0472072466797505, -0.0464084810721989, -0.0419927617067395, 
-0.0419399462514543, -0.0377372641539818, -0.0365124105553161, 
-0.036360491671919, -0.036360491671919, -0.0359305129071802, 
-0.0308720353020632, -0.026034830288271, -0.025219804873263, 
-0.0246720710831186, -0.0200073083976351, -0.01716295850615, 
-0.0131795956782751, -0.00881129823347371, -0.00832202237311769, 
-0.00782553368908862, -0.00673242091156079, -0.00401923409432514, 
-0.00130680610703465, 0.00159991939027149, 0.00275239848378878, 
0.0139737055647389, 0.0150181079458958, 0.0216866394621675, 0.0253456857888875, 
0.0273117852769699, 0.0329074339232532, 0.035451993290209, 0.0356441255788022, 
0.0371302229223923, 0.0403085737742123, 0.0405085587843396, 0.047896309185004, 
0.0484590447199657, 0.0485901658990818, 0.0516683511143709, 0.0558521216360317, 
0.0565883181814589, 0.0573815684972969, 0.0578349823771956, 0.0628161466144092, 
0.0676975000393884, 0.0736983069017554, 0.0736983069017554, 0.0736983069017554, 
0.076017247980059, 0.0804346240925511, 0.0838897490806753, 0.08457458363888, 
0.0856010762448777, 0.0887181742201171, 0.092059689743355, 0.0955398007073441, 
0.0957285740798381, 0.0961330174406444, 0.10123946135049, 0.105051862593872, 
0.107192405152092, 0.115274997058014, 0.120694319287416, 0.124413126325623, 
0.132862805827162, 0.133701627636218, 0.138867946326761, 0.140772000257388, 
0.150032904217789, 0.153353222031195, 0.154780130563657, 0.158042363913591, 
0.160927245714624, 0.162267906060427, 0.166386932605604, 0.171373785008837, 
0.172452619043718, 0.173945247360922, 0.181029937904845, 0.185921891434627, 
0.187084351713019, 0.198719226733645, 0.199042990183598, 0.199367107007842, 
0.203144383898527, 0.207760595110675, 0.224385780923984, 0.238202230407116, 
0.240459219274495, 0.251697198153391, 0.255058718789277, 0.257170640358191, 
0.30583295342159, 0.316261527700589, 0.320721487718401, 0.324418732230035, 
0.345715137038076, 0.353733516113068, 0.363305735322397, 0.371595251975644, 
0.375306761132005, 0.38475134536893, 0.395794081922032, 0.396225121853687, 
0.410788075422721, 0.419249260497744, 0.428517351732401, 0.428783555140216, 
0.430582880727231, 0.438712828684644, 0.440025544618258, 0.450440743517499, 
0.451986631356024, 0.466804393604286, 0.46707820377832, 0.471546343166024, 
0.476072465142608, 0.489391545669052, 0.495028271151588, 0.504660816209276, 
0.518096570094657, 0.519849849248616, 0.529474359826416, 0.580796232773714, 
0.590158364098142, 0.631615557792831, 0.633356343059382, 0.633934869028397, 
0.634781545493633, 0.651385992124044, 0.657091741285114, 0.659103530665497, 
0.660029095619336, 0.66918792919653, 0.66918792919653, 0.676448395307084, 
0.683199222863109, 0.68401525383931, 0.684396083147937, 0.685150861926913, 
0.692722430648078, 0.693294923571886, 0.703385594607679, 0.705169251084382, 
0.711605242083927, 0.713471241206999, 0.729720002965735, 0.746094763105927, 
0.751733435060885, 0.755667003312553, 0.766796257077811, 0.782433146247276, 
0.806489830487085, 0.879539603912491), Diff = c(-0.451253440428911, 
-0.437395110923378, -0.414199559099915, -0.393530344725446, -0.360863640366649, 
-0.314081269806454, -0.29998856781901, -0.241002392841549, -0.221270957562569, 
-0.175258505778508, -0.157952565763431, -0.142579109052732, -0.138300243185152, 
-0.131994143395042, -0.129194248421594, -0.116086141487992, -0.115070948305651, 
-0.10599561626532, -0.0647621442956714, -0.0636889296628862, 
-0.0579035622963797, -0.0572878951464517, -0.0549851853659966, 
-0.0504943468509822, -0.0502986161065477, -0.0492879526020173, 
-0.0479509804714118, -0.0479258912363667, -0.0468401004888763, 
-0.046794337259759, -0.0467896062156914, -0.0467691228212219, 
-0.0418535011956322, -0.0418535011956322, -0.0391436777261278, 
-0.0374010397287794, -0.0349304425858676, -0.0334472772545169, 
-0.0318517675818475, -0.0304827327000989, -0.0296727770520588, 
-0.0284137491149528, -0.0263795113977894, -0.0236964753049351, 
-0.0215881870132772, -0.0211343054981272, -0.0199793495608391, 
-0.0198943267357254, -0.019130285115776, -0.0186573435034587, 
-0.0181117387072938, -0.0147863452850228, -0.0111005155555954, 
-0.0107356809355252, -0.00999925208573504, -0.00869918810859627, 
-0.0073338096258091, -0.00477384814876469, -0.00477068608291109, 
-0.00371383735771058, -0.00248255344927895, 0.00124799186991265, 
0.00247367160652878, 0.00248611088207173, 0.00473195553079009, 
0.00864891863290307, 0.00874054936461643, 0.0091376483230432, 
0.00954201352911799, 0.0120323329120708, 0.0123138184322302, 
0.0132882733588469, 0.0137613422362515, 0.0143664615152916, 0.0148123134763978, 
0.0149302195504131, 0.0184199621321213, 0.0199329903135537, 0.0200259348240417, 
0.0202476527130235, 0.0215442655751019, 0.0219981625159793, 0.0221954410008163, 
0.0222917194615757, 0.0238941523168279, 0.0239566356271981, 0.0246406010229405, 
0.0256488465977034, 0.0257979870167402, 0.0295607573964407, 0.0295767060429997, 
0.0298343538853496, 0.0309721593778178, 0.0309973797373742, 0.0311030053277817, 
0.0311157353434677, 0.0322156910605775, 0.0322323701876792, 0.03359537746217, 
0.0363354631453872, 0.0370798815405582, 0.0396388385018431, 0.0399314383211502, 
0.0434581273376589, 0.0443053525838177, 0.0463800057034058, 0.0471967765588888, 
0.0472273742547324, 0.047566145043354, 0.0481858368925447, 0.0494815015880778, 
0.0523778098421079, 0.0540243208186686, 0.0551774552672413, 0.0569538028626138, 
0.0574297069824148, 0.0581231008190297, 0.0581782081242599, 0.0594261376452687, 
0.0606085349713181, 0.0616139450988928, 0.0624567849233815, 0.0639623042542059, 
0.0666778766438503, 0.0668595868037025, 0.0672018923825624, 0.0676627710896271, 
0.0677698137133032, 0.0678770638561366, 0.0691057831688546, 0.0698495577884817, 
0.071029227605357, 0.0714716432850704, 0.0763799065847559, 0.0763799065847559, 
0.0766693920447814, 0.0772916730514384, 0.0788757147078822, 0.0789355760288046, 
0.0794181736935462, 0.0797651381109654, 0.0811559712222243, 0.0812855356050246, 
0.0816579595181333, 0.0827966316466533, 0.0860869125114405, 0.0878955328776243, 
0.0892122225988334, 0.091187445393337, 0.0914185654003585, 0.0924518879514391, 
0.0925359076277887, 0.0941212248640966, 0.0953733064145368, 0.0973582137637319, 
0.0995572398446054, 0.100147506807313, 0.101793466845668, 0.102108834491799, 
0.103823633128508, 0.107851874414822, 0.109857114757617, 0.110143993809242, 
0.110359391342274, 0.112072451357714, 0.11426951928144, 0.114903209514483, 
0.116610793946559, 0.11936197023843, 0.120266506906397, 0.121810826801938, 
0.125232871461467, 0.127653979464903, 0.127926301752623, 0.130429811625166, 
0.135830212788068, 0.136041296928702, 0.136962933541573, 0.137655926386571, 
0.139504265645729, 0.141203972761406, 0.141203972761406, 0.141346880536841, 
0.142008975735597, 0.142610775344232, 0.144969832780828, 0.147449198849481, 
0.150156860342521, 0.152364471904587, 0.154751483693749, 0.154755697771369, 
0.15558889781917, 0.157237422170509, 0.157279636886165, 0.161361651047875, 
0.166222361935886, 0.166301005857372, 0.16659637255918, 0.167345555466736, 
0.168575090676804, 0.168797222340955, 0.170052611411675, 0.170108119229484, 
0.170155114496806, 0.17051782341142, 0.172522943265285, 0.172546926066097, 
0.174455308509747, 0.175011498354594, 0.175080482713441, 0.175080482713441, 
0.175275730392599, 0.177572718275409, 0.179769229196425, 0.180139321474893, 
0.180388040156121, 0.182506247292968, 0.183797829018784, 0.18560662147824, 
0.187590207664146, 0.187812381371399, 0.188037830326637, 0.188534198404255, 
0.189766220710075, 0.190997898441236, 0.192317804105979, 0.19284112964375, 
0.197936577010793, 0.198410826340645, 0.201438918443597, 0.203100443062509, 
0.203993222877519, 0.206534133036729, 0.207689583844117, 0.207776828579243, 
0.208451645758911, 0.209894892910301, 0.209985703462578, 0.213340383363581, 
0.213595914139031, 0.213655454535, 0.215053217793537, 0.21695301274034, 
0.217287309870073, 0.21764751436355, 0.217853403619039, 0.220115284522415, 
0.222331842653967, 0.225056729808948, 0.225056729808948, 0.225056729808948, 
0.22610973033077, 0.228115602491585, 0.229684529123442, 0.229995503453018, 
0.23046162019047, 0.231877053219454, 0.233394391293529, 0.234974663727083, 
0.235060383222763, 0.235244035612192, 0.23756280436058, 0.239293965422083, 
0.240265957531705, 0.243936155784796, 0.246396998446508, 0.24808565961536, 
0.251922547498196, 0.252303445404967, 0.254649402500617, 0.255514008247304, 
0.259719262444613, 0.261226974918571, 0.261874915240701, 0.263356252326807, 
0.264666239057521, 0.265275015217004, 0.267145410779035, 0.269409874603488, 
0.269899758892622, 0.270577541701167, 0.273794606123157, 0.276015977622324, 
0.276543835484344, 0.28182707859159, 0.281974095298887, 0.282121272468783, 
0.283836484025546, 0.285932644579479, 0.293481921920158, 0.299755789182932, 
0.300780658023858, 0.305883675834195, 0.307410097965755, 0.308369093662075, 
0.330466007433738, 0.335201485303527, 0.337226694253423, 0.338905564163694, 
0.348575980365995, 0.352217020420498, 0.356563638761398, 0.36032779880979, 
0.362013146106865, 0.366301807092229, 0.371316167940616, 0.371511897481658, 
0.378124742392183, 0.381966854804006, 0.386175372647646, 0.386296252099894, 
0.387113302088693, 0.390805004099426, 0.391401091070342, 0.396130495356806, 
0.396832462610686, 0.403561012777676, 0.403685346362015, 0.40571426945577, 
0.40776952167747, 0.413817540264816, 0.416377102872945, 0.420751114384976, 
0.426852112803933, 0.427648253715529, 0.43201861687634, 0.455323201671542, 
0.459574421878139, 0.478399586088751, 0.479190053691059, 0.479452754694099, 
0.479837219296519, 0.487377079248108, 0.489967984597195, 0.490881511588959, 
0.491301798412325, 0.495460703796469, 0.495460703796469, 0.498757585582132, 
0.50182304723001, 0.502193596120537, 0.502366525680698, 0.502709260757306, 
0.506147410130309, 0.506407371607187, 0.510989412076279, 0.511799346928998, 
0.514721845454025, 0.515569171015118, 0.52294751916333, 0.530383081512742, 
0.532943527988294, 0.534729709388237, 0.539783356560197, 0.546883861445457, 
0.557807684087974, 0.590978621571314)), .Names = c("month", "Variables", 
"value", "Diff"), row.names = c(NA, 357L), class = "data.frame")
```

Quero construir um gráfico usando o ggplot, porém, não quero que meu eixo x seja anos e sim que meu eixo x seja a coluna 4 de datamatrix Diff (esse meu data.frame acima):

```
ggplot(data=datamatrix, aes(x=month, y=value)) + geom_line()
```

Eu quero conservar o mesmo formato do gráfico mas mudar os valores do eixo x para os valores da coluna 4.

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o código abaixo resolve o teu problema:

```
n <- length(datamatrix$value)
datamatrix$Index <- 1:n
ticks <- floor(seq(1, n, length.out=10))
rotulos <- format(datamatrix$Diff[ticks], digits=3)

ggplot(data=datamatrix, aes(x=Index, y=value)) + geom_line() + 
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1, n), breaks=ticks, labels=rotulos)
```

[image: grafico]

Para alterar a resolução do eixo das abcissas, basta mudar o valor de `length.out=10`. Eu escolhi 10 pontos mas, em teoria, qualquer valor poderia ser utilizado. Decida de acordo com as suas preferências estéticas.

Comment: Marcus, mais uma vez, muito obrigado.